# Share posts url with prefix for GA measurement

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, mailing

We have a Wordpress site with different permalink structures and we need a way to share different post links (via email newsletter) so we can measure via GA how many visits the site receives from mail users. We were thinking on adding a prefix like newsletter but we are open to other solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to use UTM-marks for Your links in e-mails, correctly marked.